# trouble updating a deprecated cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

This is my first App. I'm trying to use the plugin [Cordova-CallLog-Plugin](https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin), but it's not working anymore. I'm using [this process](http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/installation.html) to install the plugin.

- My target platform is Android version it's 5.1.1 or 6.0, API level 22 & 23.
- Cordova -v gives me 5.4.1
- ionic -v 1.7.12.
- I've done some testing via usb plugged phone + chrome dev tool

When i'm try to call window.plugins.calllog.list, i get "window.plugins is undefined". I've found [this issue](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/SocialSharing-PhoneGap-Plugin/issues/209), which seems to indicated that the cause is a deprecated method.

From: https://github.com/dalyc/Cordova-CallLog-Plugin/blob/master/www/CallLog.js

```
CallLog.install = function () {
  if (!window.plugins) {
  window.plugins = {};
 }
window.plugins.calllog = new CallLog();
return window.plugins.calllog;
};

cordova.addConstructor(CallLog.install);
```

I've tried blindly implementing the solution from the link:

```
CallLog.install = function () {
  return calllog;
  };

module.exports = new CallLog();
```

and then

```
cordova.require("com.ubookr.plugins.calllog");
```

but now i'm getting `"module com.ubookr.plugins.calllog not found "` (but it is here in `app>plugin>com.ubookr.plugins.calllog`)

I'm a bit lost now as i'm just beginning cordova i'm not even sure i'm going in the right direction.

Appreciate any help

Update :

Just throwing that so that you can see my plugins

```
cordova plugin ls
com.ubookr.plugins.calllog 2.0 "CallLog"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.2 "Console"
cordova-plugin-contacts 1.1.0 "Contacts"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.0 "Device"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.0.0 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.0.0 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.0 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 1.0.8 "Keyboard"
```

Comment: Please answer the following questions in your post, then respond in the comments, so I know you have updated your post. Is this your first App? What is your target platform? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001)

Comment: I'have answered your questions.Thnaks

Comment: Sorry, target platform should include version. This goes for your CLI version as well. Please add to your platform.

Comment: I'm sorry i'm not sure i really understand what you mean. If you mean android version it's 5.1.1 or 6.0 api lvl 22&23 but targeting 22 for now.  Cordova -v gives me 5.4.1 and ionic -v 1.7.12. Thanks for helping

Comment: I've cleaned up your post. We'll see if someone answers.